# Calculate sum $S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}m$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Calculate sum $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ m\end{pmatrix}$$

My solution

- if $n<m$, $S=0$
- else $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}m=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ m\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{m!}\left(m!+\frac{(m+1)!}{1!}+\frac{(m+2)!}{2!}+...\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\right)$$

come here, I don't know what to do.

Comment: as written it looks undefined - are you sure it isn't $\binom m k $ instead of  $\binom  k m $

Comment: There's a closed form for this.

Comment: Why do you say it is undefined, @WW1?

Comment: because the $k=0$ term will have a factor of $\binom 0 m$ which is not defined for $m>0$

Comment: @WW1: if $k<m$$$\begin{pmatrix}k\\m\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Comment: I know the result of this problem $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\m+1\end{pmatrix}$ but I don't know what to do to this result

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n\ge m$. We have $n+1$ different doughnuts, labelled $1$ to $n+1$, lined up in a row, and want to choose $m+1$ of them for a healthy breakfast. There are $\binom{n+1}{m+1}$ ways to do it. Let us count the number of breakfast choices  **another way**.

Let $j$ be the number of the first (leftmost) doughnut chosen.

If $j=1$, we need to choose $m$ doughnut from the remaining $n$, and there are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to do it.

If $j=2$, we need to choose $m$ doughnuts from the remaining $n-1$, and there are $\binom{n-1}{m}$ ways to do it.

And so on. We obtain our sum, backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: find the generating function with respect to $m$.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ m\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ m\end{pmatrix}$$$$=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\left[\binom{k+1}{m+1}-\binom{k}{m+1}\right]$$$$=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{k+1}{m+1}}-\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{k}{m+1}$$

Setting $k+1 \mapsto k$ on the blue part follows:

$$=\sum_{k=m+1}^{n+1}\binom{k}{m+1}-\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{k}{m+1}$$$$=\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\binom{k}{m+1}-\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\binom{k}{m+1}+\binom{n+1}{m+1}$$

So:
$$S=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ m\end{pmatrix}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}}$$